# Add rows but I lose auto-fill input

Tags: jquery

I am having difficulty keeping the automatic third field insertion working. I would like to get that the user enters the rows that are needed and in each row would keep the autofill option.
Currently if I add a row it doesn't work, I even tried to increment by 1 but I probably do something wrong and went back.

https://codepen.io/bastia-g5/pen/BaOmRzP

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("input", '.variable-field', function() {
   var $row = $(this).closest('.check');
   var qty = $row.find('#quantitad_form2').val() || 0;
   $row.find('#quantitae_form2').val(Math.ceil(qty / 3));
 });
});
 
 $("#addRow").click(function(){
  
 var len=$('#dataAdd .container-fluid .form-row').length+1;
  
 //if(len>1)
  
  $("#dataAdd .container-fluid:last").append(' <div class="form-row check">'+
                   '<div class="form-group col-md-4">'+
                  ' <label></label>'+
                  ' <input class="form-control" name = "id_form'+len+'" id="id_form'+len+'" type = "number" value = "$id_form">'+
                  ' </div>'+
                  '<div class="form-group col-md-4">'+
                  '<label></label>'+
                  '<input name="quantitad_form'+len+'" value = "$quantitad_form'+len+'" class="form-control variable-field2 quantity" id="quantitad_form'+len+'" type="number">'+
                  ' </div> <div class="form-group col-md-4">'+
                  '<label></label>'+
                  '<input name="quantitae_form'+len+'" class="form-control width-80 totalcostprice" id="quantitae_form'+len+'" type="text" readonly>'+
                  '</div></div>');
  
                });
      
     $("#deleteRow").click(function(){
     var len=$('#dataAdd .container-fluid .form-row').length;
     if(len>1){
     $("#dataAdd .container-fluid .form-row").last().remove();
     }else{
     alert('Not able to Delete');
     }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <h2>Imposta quantità di stampa Dataplate</h2>
  <!--<?php
        $quantitad_form = $rows['quantita_d'];
        $quantitae_form = $rows['quantita_e'];
        $id_form = $rows['emp_id'];
        
        ?>-->
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="dataAdd">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="form-row check">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>ID</label>
            <input name="id_form" value="$id_form" type="number" id="id_form1" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Totale Dataplate</label>
            <input name="quantitad_form" value="$quantitad_form" type="number" id="quantitad_form2" class="form-control variable-field quantity" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Totale Energy Label</label>
            <input name="quantitae_form" value="$quantitae_form" type="number" id="quantitae_form2" class="form-control width-80 totalcostprice" readonly/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="addRow">Aggiungi Riga</button> <button class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteRow">Cancella Riga</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As written above, meanwhile, I would like you to be able to keep the autofill option by filling in the field in the middle.

Comment: `$('.variable-field2').on("input", function() {` only works on rows that exist at the time the code runs - change to `$(document).on("input", '.variable-field2', function() {`.  It's unclear from the code provided which field is using "auto fill" or how it's implemented.

Comment: Note: `$row.find('#quantitad_form2')` will only work on row 2 - you're already using relative navigation, so just change to classes eg `$row.find(".quantity")`

Comment: Did you see the link? Maybe it is easier to see than to write it down.
If you enter a numeric value in the middle cell a number appears that is simply the division / 3 rounded up. I would like to keep this autofill option but add rows as desired.

Comment: I enter the numerical value here: quantitad_form2 and the calculation appears here quantitae_form2.
I put in the numbers to see if it worked but nothing happens....

Comment: "*did you see the link?*" - reminder that all code for the question must be in the question itself - but yes - did you see the two comments I made above?  In the brief time I looked at your codepen, I identified two obvious issues (so there's probably more) and provided you with details above.  I'm sure someone can provide a fully-fledged answer for you.

Comment: I confirm that it is all the code, I also modified with the first suggestion and for that I thank you

Comment: *I confirm that it is all the code* - good to know - converted to a snippet for you